# How do I find the text in the following string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract time from a string that contains 3 different timestamps.

String:

```
Current time at \\\\gt2-dmsql1cst is 6/1/2015 11:59:49 AM\r\n\r\nLocal time (G
MT-05:00) at \\\\gt2-dmsql1cst is 6/1/2015 10:59:49 AM\r\n\r\nThe command comple
ted successfully.\r\n\r\n
```

I only need the time that comes after `"Local Time"`.

How can I grab this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to match everything after `Local time`, and then set a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) around the time.

```
(?si)Local time.*?(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[AP]M)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE9cO8/1)

Regex explanation:

- `(?si)` - Options to ignore case and make `.` match a newline
- `Local time.*?` - Match `Local time` and any other characters
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[AP]M)` - the capturing group with the time info:

  - `\d{2}` - Match 2 digits
  - `:` - Match literal colon
  - `\d{2}:\d{2}` - Match 2 digits, a colon and 2 digits
  - `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespaces
  - `[AP]M` - Match `AM` or `PM` or `am`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for date and time:

```
/Local time.*?((?:\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+[AP]M)/gsi
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uI3yI6/2)